Correcting negative longitudes after incorrect rendering of vector layer in QGIS
The whole layer of European soils that I took from here https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/resource-type/datasets has some of points' coordinates as negative numbers, as a result, I see this image in QGIS:

I think I should correct this. How can I do it properly and accurately?

Some parts of Russia are beyond the anti meridian

When one opens the 'sgdbe4_0' shapefile taken from the European Soil Database v2.0 in QGIS using the EPSG:4326 the Project CRS, the same visualization problem will pop up:

As I wrote before the problem is caused by the antimeridian / 180th meridian visualization, in particular, some territory of the hostile country is beyond this meridian.

There are several suggestions for this issue:

Using a different CRS e.g. EPSG:3832 or EPSG:8859 that covers the antimeridian:


Assigning the CRS based on the 'sgdbe4_0.prj', which says:

PROJCS["User_Defined_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area",GEOGCS["GCS_User_Defined",DATUM["D_User_Defined",SPHEROID["User_Defined_Spheroid",6378388.0,0.0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",48.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

So, if I choose a custom CRS or the ESRI:102017, the following result will appear:



Also, I encourage you to read the SGDBE Metadata more carefully:

4.2 - DIRECT SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM Datum: Lambert Azimuthal.
Ellipsoid: Sphere.
Map projection:  Projection    LAMBERT_AZIMUTHAL  Units
METERS             Spheroid         SPHERE  Major Axis
6378388.00000             Minor Axis       0.00000  Parameters:   radius of the sphere of reference                      6378388.00000
longitude of centre of projection                        9  0  0.000
latitude of centre of projection                        48  0  0.000
false easting (meters)                                       0.00000
false northing (meters)                                      0.00000
Height reference system:  Mean sea level.

See this thread for a more detailed explanation of the artifacts caused by the crossing of the antimeridian: Reprojecting over the Pacific Ocean with EPSG:3832 gives artefacts

References:

Unable to georeference Arrowsmith's "The World, on Mercators Projection" historical map
OpenStreetMap basemap in QGIS that shows the Pacific in the middle

